# Cucumber and Maven setup

Tags: selenium, cucumber, maven

I am trying to integrate my Cucumber project and Maven, while adding `cucumber-junit` dependency in POM, I'm getting the below error :

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.2.5
>
> org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to
>   read artifact descriptor for info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.2.5  at
>   org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:530)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:492)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:496)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:351)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:298)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54) Caused
>   by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure
>   to transfer info.cukes:cucumber-junit:pom:1.2.5 from
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact info.cukes:cucumber-junit:pom:1.2.5
>   from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed
>   out   at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
>     ... 41 more Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to
>   transfer info.cukes:cucumber-junit:pom:1.2.5 from
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact info.cukes:cucumber-junit:pom:1.2.5
>   from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed
>   out

POM xml snapshot:

```
<dependency> <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> 
<artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>  
<version>1.2.5</version> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always the issue of getting the versions of dependant libraries matching. My setup is :

```
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.4</cucumber.version>
    <selenium.version>2.53.0</selenium.version>
  </properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.11</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
          <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
          <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.zohhak</groupId>
            <artifactId>zohhak</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#junit-runner: you need to specify

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Tried adding Junit (4.12) dependency too, getting error as below :
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.2.5
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.12

Comment: Ok, can you add full pom and describe how you download dependencies? Is maven configured in eclipse to point to correct repo?

Answer (score 0):

I have added maven compiler plugin as below and its solved my problem.

```
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```